# Bash. Echo git branch -vv

Tags: git, bash, parsing, sed

Why when i'm using `echo $(git branch -vv)` it shows file list in directory, instead of branch list? How to parse `git branch -vv` via `sed` in bash script with line breaks?

Comment: Maybe you should show what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typical quoting error.

The output of the git branch command may start with a `*` which marks the currently active branch. Like this:

```
* foo                              4d49722 Unfinished
  master                           4d49722 [origin/master: 1 ahead] Unfinished
```

The shell will expand that `*` as a glob if it is not quoted. The glob expression `*` means all files or folders in the current folder.

Furthermore, the newlines will get lost because the results of a command substitution become subject to word splitting. That means the shell splits the results by `tab`, `newlines` or `space` and passes them to `echo` as individual arguments separated by spaces. That means:

```
 1
 2
 3
```

becomes `echo 1 2 3`.

The solution is to quote the command substitution:

```
echo $(git branch -vv)
```

must be:

```
echo "$(git branch -vv)"
```

---

Your second question:

> How to parse git branch -vv via sed in bash script with line breaks?

is quite vague. Please be more specific.

Comment: Oh, that explains why I didn’t run into any issue since the first branch in that list wasn’t my selected one..

Comment: Ah, good point. I was under the impression that the selected branch would be always on top of the list.

Comment: `echo "$(...)"` is almost always pointless as well. You are capturing the standard output of a command, simply to write it to standard output. Just use `git branch --v`.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I just found that this a good example to explain what can go wrong when quotes are missing.